# Is getting a value using range not thread-safe in Go?

Tags: dictionary, go

When ranging over a map `m` that has concurrent writers, including ones that could delete from the map, is it not thread-safe to do this?:

```
for k, v := range m { ... }
```

I'm thinking to be thread-safe I need to prevent other possible writers from changing the value `v` while I'm reading it, and (when using a mutex and because locking is a separate step) verify that the key `k` is still in the map. For example:

```
for k := range m {
    m.mutex.RLock()
    v, found := m[k]
    m.mutex.RUnlock()
    if found {
        ... // process v
    }
}
```

(Assume that other writers are write-locking `m` before changing `v`.) Is there a better way?

Edit to add: I'm aware that maps aren't thread-safe. However, they are thread-safe in one way, according to the Go spec at http://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements (search for "If map entries that have not yet been reached are deleted during iteration"). This page indicates that code using `range` needn't be concerned about other goroutines inserting into or deleting from the map. My question is, does this thread-safe-ness extend to `v`, such that I can get `v` *for reading only* using only `for k, v := range m` and no other thread-safe mechanism? I created some test code to try to force an app crash to prove that it doesn't work, but even running blatantly thread-unsafe code (lots of goroutines furiously modifying the same map value with no locking mechanism in place) I couldn't get Go to crash!

Comment: Just a comment (less for OP who probably already knows it than for other readers) : http://golang.org/doc/go_faq.html#atomic_maps

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No, map operations are not atomic/thread-safe**, as the commenter to your question pointed to [the golang FAQ “Why are map operations not defined to be atomic?”](http://golang.org/doc/go_faq.html#atomic_maps).

To secure your accessing it, you are encouraged to use Go's **[channels](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Channel_types) as a means of resource access token**. The channel is used to simply pass around a token. Anyone wanting to modify it will request so from the channel - blocking or non-blocking. When done with working with the map it passes the token back to the channel.

Iterating over and working with the map should be sufficiently simple and short, so you should be ok using just one token for full access.

If that is not the case, and you use the map for more complex stuff/a resource consumer needs more time with it, you may implement a reader- vs writer-access-token. So at any given time, only one writer can access the map, but when no writer is active the token is passed to any number of readers, who will not modify the map (thus they can read simultaneously).

For an introduction to channels, see [the Effective Go docs on channels](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#channels).

Comment: Thanks for the response! I edited my question to emphasize that I'm wondering if `for k, v := range m { ... }` is thread-safe for `v` for reading only. The Go spec indicates that `range` is thread-safe as far as other goroutines inserting into or deleting from the map. I know about channels, but if getting `v` using `range` is already thread-safe, that's all I'd need.

Comment: OK, looking around some more, like [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/golang-nuts/map$20range/golang-nuts/eJqwQLONhLs/3YFEjIe57wMJ), I see that your answer is correct. It seems that to be thread-safe it is necessary to lock a whole map before using `range` on it, if other goroutines will write to (update, delete, or modify) the same keys being iterated over. The section from the Go spec I referred to is talking about a single thread that is deleting from or inserting into the map it's ranging over, and how that thread *affects itself*.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [concurrent-map](https://github.com/streamrail/concurrent-map) to handle the concurrency pains for you.

```
// Create a new map.
map := cmap.NewConcurretMap()

// Add item to map, adds "bar" under key "foo"
map.Add("foo", "bar")

// Retrieve item from map.
tmp, ok := map.Get("foo")

// Checks if item exists
if ok == true {
    // Map stores items as interface{}, hence we'll have to cast.
    bar := tmp.(string)
}

// Removes item under key "foo"
map.Remove("foo")
```